# How to create logs on HDFS with a log4j custom appender?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, log4j

**Overview**

We want to log our Spark job activity using log4j to write log files to HDFS.

- Java 8, Spark 2.4.6, Scala 2.1.2, Hadoop 3.2.1

We were unable to find a native apache log4j appenders to write to HDFS (Apache Flume in not an option), so set out to write our own.

Scala logic matched Java, however, logging to the custom appender fails consistently with a Stack overflow error.

We cannot find anything obviously wrong?

**The implementation:**

Here is a simple hello-world project to reproduce the issue:

- Scala / Java project (Maven build), containing a simple main class, and:
- HDFSAppender class (extends log4j AppenderSkeleton)
- LoggingTest unit test class
- log4j configuration file for testing

**HDFSAppender.scala  - Appender class**

````
```
package com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.URI
import java.net.URISyntaxException

import scala.beans.BeanProperty

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.MDC
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent
import org.apache.logging.log4j.scala.Logging
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object HDFSAppender {
  def createAndRegister(): HDFSAppender = {
    val hdfsAppender: HDFSAppender = new HDFSAppender
    Logger.getRootLogger.addAppender(hdfsAppender)
    hdfsAppender
  }

  def setClassLoggerLevel(clazz: Class[_], logLevel: Level): Level = {
    val logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz)
    val previousLevel = logger.getLevel
    Logger.getLogger(clazz).setLevel(logLevel)
    previousLevel
  }

  def unregister(hdfsAppender: HDFSAppender): Unit = {
    Logger.getRootLogger.removeAppender(hdfsAppender)
  }
}


class HDFSAppender extends AppenderSkeleton with Logging {

  var sc: SparkContext = _
  
  @BeanProperty
  var file: String = null

  @BeanProperty
  var URI: String = null

  override def close(): Unit = {}

  override def requiresLayout(): Boolean = true

  override protected def append(event: LoggingEvent): Unit = {
    var success: Boolean = false
    val log: String = this.layout.format(event)
    val uri: URI = new URI(this.URI)
    
    write(this.URI, file, log)
    
  }
    
  def write(uriString: String, file: String, log: String): Unit = {
    val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
    MDC.put("eventName", "HDFSLogWriterWrite");
    
    
    val uri: URI = new URI(uriString)
    val logPath: Path = new Path(uriString + file)
    
    val fs = getFS(uri,conf)
    var output_stream: FSDataOutputStream = null
    try {
      if ((fs.exists(logPath) && fs.getFileStatus(logPath).isFile)) {
        output_stream = fs.append(logPath, 512)
      } else {
        output_stream = fs.create(logPath, true, 512)
      }
      val buffered_output: BufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(output_stream)
      buffered_output.write(log.getBytes("UTF-8"))
      buffered_output.close()   
      
    } catch {
      
      case e: IOException => {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
       case e: URISyntaxException => {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
    /**
   * return a FileSystem from URI
   */
  private def getFS(uri: URI, conf: Configuration): FileSystem = {
    var fs: FileSystem = null
    try {
      fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    fs
  }
}
````

**Test class**

````
```
package com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.test

import java.net.URI

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.junit.Assert.assertTrue
import org.junit.BeforeClass
import org.junit.Test
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite

import com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.CustomJsonEventLayout
import com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.HDFSAppender

import LoggingTest.fsHDFS
import LoggingTest.testHDFSHost
import LoggingTest.testOutputLogPath


object LoggingTest {
  
  var fsHDFS: FileSystem = _
  
  val testHDFSHost: String = 
    "hdfs://localhost:9000"
  
  val testOutputLogPath: String =
    "/test/ut/logging/log-test-hdfs-appender_scala.txt"

  @BeforeClass
  def setupFsRemovePreviousTestFiles(): Unit = {
    
    val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", testHDFSHost)
    fsHDFS = FileSystem.get(new URI(testHDFSHost), conf)
    val outputPath: Path = new Path(testOutputLogPath)
    if (fsHDFS.exists(outputPath)) {
      fsHDFS.delete(outputPath, true)
    }
  }

}

/**
 * programmatically builds and tests logging events with log4j.test
 *
 */
class LoggingTest extends JUnitSuite {
  val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()

  @Test
  def testHDFSAppender(): Unit = {
    val hdfsAppender: HDFSAppender = new HDFSAppender()
    val rootlogger: Logger = LogManager.getRootLogger
   
    hdfsAppender.setFile(testOutputLogPath)
    hdfsAppender.setURI(testHDFSHost)
    hdfsAppender.setThreshold(Level.ALL)
    hdfsAppender.setLayout(new CustomJsonEventLayout())
    rootlogger.addAppender(hdfsAppender)
    val logger: Logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass)

    try {
      logger.info("Test info message")
      logger.warn("Test warn message")
      logger.error("Test error message")
      logger.debug("Test debug message")
    } finally {
     logger.removeAppender(hdfsAppender)
  }
    val logFile: Path = new Path(testHDFSHost + testOutputLogPath)
    assertTrue(fsHDFS.exists(logFile))
    // TODO: further assertions to check log contents

  }
}
````

**log4j configuration file (run-time testing)**

````
```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, HDFSAppender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5p] [%X{eventName}] %m %c%n    
log4j.appender.HDFSAppender=com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.HDFSAppender
log4j.appender.HDFSAppender.layout=com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.CustomJsonEventLayout
log4j.appender.HDFSAppender.file=/test/ut/logging/log-test-hdfs-appender_scala.json
log4j.appender.HDFSAppender.URI=hdfs://localhost:9000
log4j.appender.HDFSAppender.threshold=DEBUG
````

Any logging event causes the program to crash with a stack overflow error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:506)
 at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
 at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
```

Then the following messages appear, implying some kind of loop/race condition

```
 at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
   at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
   at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
   at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
   at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
   at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.warn(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:401)
   at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logWarning(Logging.scala:66)
   at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logWarning$(Logging.scala:65)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.logWarning(SparkContext.scala:2442)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$5(SparkContext.scala:2500)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.$anonfun$assertNoOtherContextIsRunning$5$adapted(SparkContext.scala:2491)
   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.assertNoOtherContextIsRunning(SparkContext.scala:2491)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.markPartiallyConstructed(SparkContext.scala:2568)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:85)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$5(SparkSession.scala:935)
   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:138)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:926)
   at com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.HDFSLogWriter.write(HDFSLogWriter.scala:23)
   at com.obfuscated.test.spark.log4j.HDFSAppender.append(HDFSAppender.scala:63)
(repeats 48 times...)
```

**Maven Dependencies**

```
Downloaded from central: 

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/alchim31/maven/scala-maven-plugin/3.2.2/scala-maven-plugin-3.2.2.jar (119 kB at 163 kB/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< spark-hello-world-scala:spark-hello-world-scala >-----------
[INFO] Building spark-hello-world-scala 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ spark-hello-world-scala ---
[INFO] spark-hello-world-scala:spark-hello-world-scala:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.12:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm7-shaded:jar:4.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-sslengine:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-kvstore_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.4-3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.7.45:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.roaringbitmap:shims:jar:0.7.45:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.12:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.12:jar:3.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.12:jar:3.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.12:jar:3.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.12:jar:3.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.25.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.47.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jmx:jar:4.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.razorvine:pyrolite:jar:4.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.10.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.12:jar:3.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.12:jar:3.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-graphx_2.12:jar:3.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.fommil.netlib:core:jar:1.1.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sourceforge.f2j:arpack_combined_all:jar:0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-mllib-local_2.12:jar:3.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.scalanlp:breeze_2.12:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scalanlp:breeze-macros_2.12:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:jar:3.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- pl.edu.icm:JLargeArrays:jar:1.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.chuusai:shapeless_2.12:jar:2.3.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.typelevel:macro-compat_2.12:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.typelevel:spire_2.12:jar:0.17.0-M1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.typelevel:spire-macros_2.12:jar:0.17.0-M1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.typelevel:spire-platform_2.12:jar:0.17.0-M1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.typelevel:spire-util_2.12:jar:0.17.0-M1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.typelevel:machinist_2.12:jar:0.6.8:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.typelevel:algebra_2.12:jar:2.0.0-M2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.typelevel:cats-kernel_2.12:jar:2.0.0-M4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.12:jar:2.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:runtime
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:runtime
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:runtime
[INFO] +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.8:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:jar:0.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:jar:0.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory:jar:0.15.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.google.flatbuffers:flatbuffers-java:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-core:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-shims:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.airlift:aircompressor:jar:0.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.threeten:threeten-extra:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.orc:orc-mapreduce:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-storage-api:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:jar:1.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:jar:3.0.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.scalactic:scalactic_2.12:jar:3.0.5:test
[INFO] +- org.specs2:specs2-core_2.12:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.specs2:specs2-matcher_2.12:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.specs2:specs2-common_2.12:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.specs2:specs2-fp_2.12:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.scala-sbt:test-interface:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] +- org.specs2:specs2-junit_2.12:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api-scala_2.12:jar:12.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:test-jar:tests:2.13.3:test
[INFO] \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.13.3:compile
```

Comment: I don't think its a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - can you expand on why its not a good idea?

Comment: With further testing, it is clear this issue is true for a Java implementation with equivalent code as well - my initial tests returned a false positive on a local mode + HDFS in Junit

Comment: Were you able to get this working in the meantime @ThomasHumphries?

Answer (score 1):

The `StackOverflowError` is normal given that your code did not implement a `ThreadLocal` marker to avoid reentrant calls.
Internally, any HDFS implementation class may call `log.info()`, thereby creating a recursive `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Are you saying that `log.info()` is recursive, i.e. method `info()` calls itself, infinitely, thus causing a `StackOverflowError`?