# Can I give dataproc's log4j.properties file having log4j.appender.file.File as gcs path?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, log4j, log4j2, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to store my custom application logs to GCS folder.

my current log4j.properties is like below:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console

# define console appender
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

#application log
log4j.logger.surya.pyspark.poc=INFO, console, file
log4j.additivity.surya.pyspark.poc=false

#define rolling file appender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=gs://dataproc-gs/surya/surya_app_logs.log
```

If i'm giving the path like this... its not storing in GCS. Any suggestions please..?

I also tried giving **spark.driver.extraJavaOptions** in spark-submit properties. but still its not working.

Comment: No, log4j doesn't support GCS.

Answer (score 1):

No, log4j doesn't support HDFS or GCS as a appender, but you can implement a custom appender for it, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63276838/how-to-create-logs-on-hdfs-with-a-log4j-custom-appender).